# History of the notion of "cryptarchy" ("secret government")

Tags: political-theory, history, reference-request

The [*Oxford English Dictionary*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/275800) defines "[cryptarchy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/275800)" as:

> *rare.*
>   Secret government; an example of this.

What is the history of this notion? Did any famous political philosophers write about cryptarchies? If so, who? What did they say?

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work (paywalled?)

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like the Protoc- [ the remainder of this post has been censored ].  However, that's all just conspiracy theory.

Comment: Are you thinking about the idea of State-level secret governments or something world-wide like the New World Order theory?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, it is. I just put it for reference. The full entry isn't much more than what I quoted. It just contains two quotes, from 1798 (W. Taylor in _Monthly Rev._ **25** 511) and 2006.

Comment: @A.Darwin I'm looking for more of a theoretical discussion of them, not a discussion on particular instances of cryptarchies.

Comment: Interesting concept; and one that I haven't come across before, even if it's not referenced in political theory as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No.

I spent a lot of time in political theory courses, including some time spent with original Greek texts.  However, never once did I hear of anything called a "cryptarchy" or any philosopher espousing a kind of secret government.

Personal observation is weak, so here are a few other things to consider:

- [Google NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cryptarchy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) can search Google Books for words in Google's dictionary. 'Cryptarchy' is obscure enough that isn't in their NGrams dictionary.
- [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=cryptarchy,technocracy) shows that each month, at most about 13 people searched for 'cryptarchy'. That is tiny. For comparison, I plotted it against 'technocracy' - an obscure term from some sci-fi movies (and an even more obscure American movement from about the 1920s-1930s ). At minimum it saw three times as many searches.
- The citations in OED (which the question links to) are from cases where the source appear to coin the term in a fairly ad hoc manner. The cited examples aren't referencing some known idea of a cryptarchy, they are forming a new word to describe something they have observed.

However, some sources have described kinds of secret governments. For example, Thucydides in *The History of the Peloponnesian War* describes several revolts and secret governments.  One example is Corcyra, where an oligarchy led a revolt against Athens. In modern language, we probably wouldn't call them a "government", but Greek politics at this time was far less institutional, and that label makes more sense. You can find an analysis of this section [here](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~bzarit/thucydides.html) (published by Tufts University)

Comment: What was the Greek work that Thucydides used for "secret government"?

Comment: @Geremia - He doesn't give a name to this group. They are originally a group of prisoners of war returned to Corcyra to incite revolt. So he calls them "αἰχμάλωτος" - "prisoners". http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Thuc.+3.70&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0199

Comment: @Geremia - There is also a revolt in Athens in the same book. To my recollection, the conspirators are just called "oligarchs".